# Finding the maximum value between certain row and columns in pandas df

Tags: csv, pandas, dataframe

Suppose, I have the dataframe below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group1': ['x','xincr','xmin','xzero','yzero','ymin','s','0','1','2','3','4','5'],
                    'value1': [1.1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4]})
```

I want to find the maximum value in column `'value1'` starting in row 7-12. Is there a way to make that specification?

Furthermore, can the output just be the value (i.e. 9).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of mixed indexing.  Meaning you want to use labels for the columns and positions for the rows.  There are a few ways to do this.

***Option 1***

Use `.value1` to specify the columns then `iloc` to specify the rows 7 through 12 using `6:12`.

```
df.value1.iloc[6:12].max()

9.0
```

***Option 2***

```
df.iloc[6:12, df.columns.get_loc('value1')].max()
```

***Option 3***

```
df.value1.values[6:12].max()
```

Any more options and I'll feel silly.  This should do.

Comment: Sorry I meant in column 'value1'. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @A.Dizzle can you fix your question?

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm new to python so thanks for helping out.